# R ggplot2 geom_smooth wihtout adding negative values

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

Assume that we ran
`install.packages("ggplot2")`
`install.packages("babynames")`

Then

```r
library(babynames)
data(babynames)
my_d <- babynames %>%
  filter(
    name == "Josiah"   & sex == "M" |
      name == "Alicia"  & sex == "F" |
      name == "Gabriel"  & sex == "M" |
      name == "Joshua" & sex == "M"
  ) %>%
  group_by(name, year, sex) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(n) ) %>%
  arrange(year)

ggplot(my_d, aes(x = year, y = n, color = name) ) +
  geom_line(se = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1900, 2020, by = 10) )
```

gives

[image]

It is nice but I would like to smooth it "a little", so I do

```r
ggplot(my_d, aes(x = year, y = n, color = name) ) +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1900, 2020, by = 10) )
```

which gives
[image]

This is smooth, but it added negative values for "Joshua".

How could I avoid that "side effect"?

EDIT: Changing

```
geom_smooth(se = FALSE)
```

to

```
geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = "loess") +
  ylim(0, 30000)
```

removes negative values but the "smoothing is still to coarse, so too speak. It shows "Gabriel" with an increasing trend, which it is not.
Here is the result

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In ggplot restrict y to be >0 in LOESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777053/in-ggplot-restrict-y-to-be-0-in-loess)

Comment: It does not look like it does, I added an EDIT to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `span =` argument should makes the smoothing "wigglier" according to the [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html).  Maybe playing around with that will solve your problem.  Below is an example with `span = .1`.  The rough edges are gone from the lines, but general trends tend to remain visible and true.  Setting `span` too low may cause memory issues depending on the size of the data.

```r
library(babynames)
library(tidyverse)
data(babynames)
my_d <- babynames %>%
  filter(
    name == "Josiah"   & sex == "M" |
      name == "Alicia"  & sex == "F" |
      name == "Gabriel"  & sex == "M" |
      name == "Joshua" & sex == "M"
  ) %>%
  group_by(name, year, sex) %>%
  summarise( n = sum(n) ) %>%
  arrange( year )

ggplot( my_d, aes(x = year, y = n, color = name) ) +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = "loess", span = .1) +
  scale_x_continuous( breaks = seq(1900, 2020, by = 10) )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>